# Google places autocomplete suggestion without country name

Tags: api, autocomplete, google-places, country

I am looking for a possibility to get suggestions without country name.

I have the following js code:

```
... var autocomplete_pickup = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pickup_field, {
       types: ["address"], componentRestrictions: {country: "de"}
}); ...
```

The result is e.g.

```
Bahnhofstrasse 4, Hamburg, Deutschland
```

Now I want to have for that example only

```
Bahnhofstrasse 4, Hamburg
```

I have limited the countries only to Germany and therefore is not necessary to show the country name.

Do you have an idea?
Thanks.
Heinz-Peter

Answer (score 3):

For resolve it, just add this query param `&region=de` into your script path

It seems like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-KEY]&libraries=places&region=de"></script>
```

It helped me.